# Error uploading a file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to upload an image in my `Laravel` application. Everything works fine in `localhost`. I've tested many times.

So, I've uploaded all files to the server and tested it again. Now when I upload an image, I'm getting the following error:

> {"error":{"type":"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException","message":"","file":"/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php","line":210}}`

Not sure what's wrong in this. Everything is working fine in locahost. I'm using  `Ubuntu 14.02` in my server. `GD` library is installed and activated. `Composer` update has run and all packages are installed.

What might be the problem? Let me know if you need any code snippets. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run `php artisan routes` (or `php artisan route:list` for Laravel 5) and see if the route you're uploading to exists and is correct.

Comment: There is an extra `/` at the trailing part of the URL. Would that make any problem?

Comment: I changed the `/` at the end it removed the `301 permanently moved` error. Now it shows the following errors: `{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"copy(\/var\/www\/html\/public\/\/upload\/20150413032940.jpeg): failed to open stream: Permission denied","file":"\/var\/www\/html\/app\/controllers\/NominationController.php","line":88}}`

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. Seems like you don't have writing permissions with the user that the webserver uses

Comment: That depends... You can use `chown user:group /path/to/directory` to change the ownership of the directory. or use `chmod 775 /path/to/directory` to make it writeable for all users in the owners group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this was a file permissions issue.

Running `php artisan routes` (or `php artisan route:list` for Laravel 5) helped to sort out another problem so the real error message appeared:

> {"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"copy(/var/www/html/public//u‌​pload/20150413032940.jpeg): failed to open stream: Permission denied","file":"/var/www/html/app/controllers/NominationController.php","l‌​ine":88}}

This means the webserver's user can't write to `public/upload`. This can be fixed by two methods (the choice depends on preference and setup)

1. `chown user:group /path/to/directory` to change the ownership of the directory
2. `chmod 775 /path/to/directory` to make the directory writable for all users in the owner's group

Comment: Just one more thing to add: Remove any trailing slash `/` for the Ajax call if it's not defined in the route. 

I had problem with calling the ajax: `example.com/upload/image/` I changed it to `example.com/upload/image` and it worked. Otherwise you'll get a `301 permanently moved` error message.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the route which is called when you submit your form is accessible by your form's submission method (e.g. GET if its method attribute is 'GET')

For instance,

```
Route::get('/upload', ...)
```

With

```
<form action="/upload" method="post">...</form>
```

in your view would cause the error you get.

Comment: I'm uploadig via Ajax. Some other ajax methods are working well. Only the Image uploading is not working

Comment: Can you post your route definition, and a basic version of your uploading script ? 
Are you sure that your route's URL doesn't match another one which only accepts the wrong HTTP method ?

Comment: I don't understand, everything is working very well in the localhost. So what might be the problem with the server?

Comment: To be honest I have no clue, but maybe posting some code snippets could help me (or someone else) to figure something out... Quite strange, though.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue and after checking permissions etc it was still occurring... I just tried removing the LEADING slash from the path I had set in my .env file and it worked (even though it was relative to the webserver's public directory so theoretically should have worked with a leading slash denoting to start at webserver root dir)

IMAGE_LIB_PATH="blah/blahblah/"

Anyhow, hope this helps someone.